# Microservices architecture tutorial for springboot and react in production

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

My project contains two apps. Backend – springboot and a frontend - React.

I am using the spring-boot app only as a rest API to fetch data from the database. The React app frontend will call the API. Up until now, we were using only one environment (Windows) so production build was one jar that actually contains both apps and a tomcat. That was quite simple so by adding a proxy in the package.json file to point to the backend and some maven(frontend-maven-plugin) plugin the building process is simple.

Now we need to change the system architecture so each app will be hosts on a different windows machine.

I was trying to use express to host the react app but I am struggling with the proxy setup for the backend (spring) app from the express server. All the tutorials that I found actually using the express server as the backend API but I need the express server only for hosting the production build.

Is there a good tutorial that shows how to set up this type of architecture in production env.

Thank you

Comment: I use Nginx as the web server for both static content and spring-boot apps. Makes the proxying very easy. I highly recommend it. My spring-boot I package as a runnable service - builds with its own tomcat embedded in the app using the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Comment: Thank you Kieveli. I am using windows server and Nginx is not performing so good on windows.